# How does random_state=0 and random_state= numpy.random.RandomState(0) differ from each other?

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, random-seed

I am testing some possibilities around `random_state`. Can you explain how `random_state = 0` and `random_state = numpy.random.RandomState(0)` differ from each other ?

**Code**

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import numpy as np
import random

for i in range(5):
    
    ###########  code for random_state= numpy.random.RandomState(i) ##############
    
    rng = np.random.RandomState(i)
    X, y = make_classification(random_state=rng)
    rf = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=rng)
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y,
                                                        random_state=rng)
    p1=rf.fit(X_train, y_train).score(X_test, y_test)
    
   ###########  code for random_state= integer ##############

    X, y = make_classification(random_state=i)
    rf = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=i)
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y,
                                                        random_state=i)
    p2=rf.fit(X_train, y_train).score(X_test, y_test)
    print(i,p1,p2)
```

**Output**

```
0  0.84   0.92
1  1.0    0.92
2  0.88   0.92
3  0.84   0.88
4  1.0    1.0
```

Comment: I think `random_state = 0` doesn't use random value and you always will have the same results. But `rng = np.random.RandomState(i)` can generate random values whenever you use `rng`. Try to use the same `rng` to create two trees and you get different results. Try to use the same `i` to create two trees and you get the same results.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the `random_state = 1` sets a fixed seed (e.g. 1) for the splitting of train/test sets.

Setting the `random_state = np.random.RandomState(1)` will set the seed as a random variable with seed 1. At each iteration, `np.random.RandomState` instance will change randomly each time, splitting in a non repeatable way the sets.

Use a normal integer as `random_state` if you want repeatable splits, or use nothing to have random splits.

Using `RandomState` makes sense only if you want to split randomly your sets according to some particular distribution (with fixed seed). See [the official numpy docs about it](https://numpy.org/doc/1.14/reference/generated/numpy.random.RandomState.html)